# Redirect express to React page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am a newbie in React and Node. I have two folders:

1. Client, hosted on 3000
2. Server, express on 3001

Registration worked fine form me, but after authentication `successRedirect:` to `http://localhost:3001/login`

How to redirect it to client at `http://localhost:3000/login`

```
passport.authenticate('local-signup',{
  successRedirect:'/login',
  failureRedirect: '/register',
  failureFlash : true  
})(req, res);
```

Comment: Unless your authentication request is non-AJAX, you will need to call `res.redirect` in the `authenticate` callback.

Comment: how to setup this on passport ?

Comment: you don't setup anything on passport, you just need to redirect the URL in the callback...

Comment: please give an example :(

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)

Comment: not redirecting, 404

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a fully qualified `url` to the redirects as mentioned in Express Api [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)

One of the ways you can achieve this is by setting up a call back function using `redirect` on the `response` property , (You can amend this accordingly ) :

```
app.get("/auth/google/callback"",
    passport.authenticate("local-signup"),
    (req , res) => {
        res.redirect("/login");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try handling this logic on the React side of things. Personally I use an endpoint `/auth/verify` which sends back one of two json objects: `{ auth: true, user: [user data] }` or `{ auth: false, user: null }`. Then, in the React app, I set the value of `auth` in state and use a `Redirect` from `react-router` to redirect me to the page I need based on the new value in state.